# Everything in csv file converted to int64?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to work with a csv file(link:https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/tips.csv) on jupyter notebook. When I perform .dtypes to the file it only returns the result dtype('int64') and nothing else. How can I get other data types such as float64 and object for every columns?

Also I'm using the file from uploading the csv file to jupyter notebook. Used the code below to read it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('tips.csv')
```

It's weird because when I ran the exact same code yesterday it showed data types for each column. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: What code do you use when you say 'perform .dtypes to the file'? `df.dtypes`? or something else?

Comment: Yes I used that exact code

Comment: Check the contents of your `'tips.csv'` file -- did you incidentally over-write it? When I download the linked file, and `pd.read_csv` it, I get 2x `float64`, 4x `object`, and 1x `int64` column

Comment: Or, what is the output for `df.head()`?

Comment: total_bill    0
tip              0
smoker      0
day            0
time           0
dtype: int64

Comment: Somewhere along the line, either `'tips.csv'` got overwritten, or `df` got modified. Short solution: download the file again from your link, and run `df = pd.read_csv('tips.csv')` again.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp
This is the output for df.head(), which I don't know why it's showing up like this. Also it's lacking some columns from the original dataset from the link because it was altered by someone else. However everyone who tried the same thing with the altered data got normal results so I think there must be a problem with my laptop

Answer (score 1):

The local file on your laptop isn't what you think it is; check the output of

```py
import csv
with open('tips.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for _ in range(2):
    print(next(reader))
```

and confirm that your local copy of `'tips.csv'` is missing data. Re-download the file from your linked source if needed.